# Dimention of span of subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb R$ and $B = { v_1,v_2,v_3 }$ a base of $V$.
$S = { v1-v2, v2-v3, v3+v1 }$

$A$. is $S$ a base of $V$?
$B$. is $\dim(\text{span}(s)) = 1$ ?

---

I really hope I correctly proved that $A$ indeed is true. 
I am really finding it hard to handle $B$. Can someone please help?

Thanks,

Tom.

Comment: What is the dimension of $V$?

Comment: B = {v1,v2,v3 } a Base of V so I it is 3, isn't it?

Comment: So, what do this and your answer to part A say about part B?

Comment: Intuitively it is 3, isn't spanS infinite set, or am I just misunderstanding and it simply means that from spanS I can create infinite amount of Linearily dependent vectors of V.

Comment: Try to figure out the meaning of the definitions of a basis and a linear span: A basis for $V$ is a linearly independent set of vectors such that every vector in $V$ can be expressed as a linear combination of these vectors. The linear span of a set $S$ is the set of all vectors which can be expressed as a linear combination of the elements (vectors) of $S$. So what is the span of a basis?

Comment: The Vector Space?

Answer (score 1):

$V$ is 3-dimensional, hence any three linearly independent vectors form a basis of $V$. If $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearly independent, then
$$0=\lambda_1(v_1-v_2) + \lambda_2(v_2-v_3) + \lambda_3(v_3+v_1) = (\lambda_1+\lambda_3)v_1 + (\lambda_2-\lambda_1)v_2 + (\lambda_3-\lambda_2)v_3$$
implies $0=\lambda_1+\lambda_3=\lambda_2-\lambda_1=\lambda_3-\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=0$ follows. Thus, $S$ consists of three linearly independent vectors, so that $S$ is a basis of $V$.

Since $S$ consists of three linearly independent vectors, $dim(span(S))=3$.